# reCAPTCHA on Chrome Content Scripts

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script, recaptcha

I am trying to make Google `reCAPTCHA` works on my Chrome extension of type Content Scripts but it is not working nor displaying any message in the Chrome logs window.

The reCAPTCHA is not displaying when deploying the extension in Developer mode, but it is displayed when open the extension HTML file.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Yea, solution is here: https://github.com/MuhammadHewedy/cobone-reviews